# Visual Studio 2012 is searching for project in the wrong path?

Tags: c#, vb.net, path, project, visual-studio-2012

When I try to load a project in VS2012 the load fail an says that it can't find my project file in location `C:\...`

But, this location isn't the one found in the project file or the solution file.

Does anyone know where I can find/change the wrong path ref.?

Comment: just edit the csproj (vbproj) or sln file using your text editor and update the path

Comment: I have tried and both files ref the correct path, but still vs wants the wrong one. Even tried reinstalling vs and reloaded the workspace. But nothing changes. Could there be a registry entry of some kind that overrides the sln or vbproj?

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I closed the solution; checked the workspace mappings; then turning on 'view hidden folders' in Windows Explorer shows a new (to VS2012) '$tf' directory and the SUO files

I completely deleted the directory on the local hard drive (to be sure) and then did a "Get Specific Version" with the "Overwrite all files even if the local..." option ticked; forcing a complete download.

Comment: I've too had an issue with Visual Studio looking in completely wrong locations for projects, even when adding an existing project by navigating the file-system and selecting the csproj-file in a file-picker dialog.

It seems like for whatever reason, since this was under source-control, VS kept some sort of cache in the SUO-files and deleting those gets things back working like they should.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved! After a restart of the Team Foundation Server the problem went away. The answers to this post make a good summary to what to check in case of problems with projects in Visual Studio. Thank you all for your efforts.